# Unable to Build or clean Visual Studio 2015 Solution (Access Denied)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

It was working fine a few hours ago , then I shut down my computer. Now when I re-open visual studio and build my solution again, I get this error :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.BuildSteps.Targets(173,5): error MSB3061: Unable to delete file "x64\Debug\GEnx11.tlog\GEnx11.lastbuildstate". Access to the path 'G:\VS2015_PROJECTS\Projects\GEnx11\GEnx11\x64\Debug\GEnx11.tlog\GEnx11.lastbuildstate' is denied.

Please Help...Thanks..!!!

Comment: Try looking at the file referenced in your error to make sure it is not set to readonly.

Comment: I removed read-only property from the whole folder and subfolders..still same error

Comment: Have you tried manually deleting the file it was trying to delete ?

Comment: yes it will make the file again of size 0 kb and throw access denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start Visual Studio as an administrator. may be this could help you.

Comment: where is the exe located for some reason my windows search is not working suddenly!!!

Comment: you can find it under program files

Comment: Worked thanks a ton!!! But why suddenly it stopped building , ive never launched vs in admin mode before and it used to work.

Comment: it was trying to delete some file which only administrator has permission to delete. you can accept it as answer if it worked for you